# Copying element within an array and assigning it to multiple positions in a new array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, copy, python-xarray

Suppose I have an array A

```
[i1, i2, i3]
```

and I wish to copy its elements to array B but while expanding them such that array B is

```
[i1, i1, i1, i1, i2, i2, i2, i2, i3, i3, i3, i3]
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `b = []; b += (x for x in ["i1", "i2", "i3"] for y in range(4)); print(b)`

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import chain
from functools import reduce

starting_list = [1, 2, 3]
ending_list = []

for element in starting_list:
    extended_element = [element]*3
    ending_list = ending_list + extended_element


# fancy way
temp = chain([[element]*3 for element in starting_list])
ending_list2 = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, temp)

print(ending_list)
print(ending_list2)
```